# can't open iframe-window in jquery thickbox

Tags: jquery, iframe, thickbox

I'm trying to open a iframe thickbox window with the following URL:

`< a id="thickbox2" title="Contact us" href="/send.php?keepThis=true&#38;TB_iframe=true&#38;height=370&#38;width=300" class="blue_link">Contact us < / a >`

The thickbox black background loads and the progress bar is shown, but not the send.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself; I had a "home made" and unknown bug in my thickbox.js file. When I replaced it with a new one, everything worked out great.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you load the send.php file directly in the browser?

I'm wondering if the send.php file exists and/or whether it's responding correctly (i.e. generating HTML output instead of chucking a server error.)

Comment: it loads correctly. it also loads correctly when im not using the keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true parameters. the html in send.php is a div containing a form.

Comment: Baffling.  Two more daft things to check: the send.php form's on the same domain-name isn't it? And... are you testing this on a live website, or with a local HTML file?

Comment: One more daft thing... does the progress bar go away?  (I'm wondering if there are any style rules making the `iframe` inisible?)

Comment: Yes, its on the same domain and on a live website. The progress bar does not go away. It seems like the loading stop and begin to hang.